# SQL match function written by me taking too much time. Optimization required

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is the sample test data for which the function should return 1 for anything else it should return 0:

```
Inventor: Raj Patel
Attorney: Raj Patel

Inventor: Patel; Raj
Attorney: Patel

Inventor: Patel; R
Attorney: Patel; Raj

Inventor: Patel; Raj, Madnani; Raj
Attorney: Patel; Raj

Inventor: Patel; Raj
Attorney: Patel; R


**Eg.** Select dbo.Match('Patel; R','Patel; Raj')
```

**All these executions should return 1:**

```
Select dbo.Match('Raj Patel','Raj Patel')
Select dbo.Match('Patel; Raj','Patel')
Select dbo.Match('Patel; R',' Patel; Raj')
Select dbo.Match('Patel; Raj, Madnani; Raj','Patel; Raj')
Select dbo.Match('Patel; Raj','Patel; R')
```

should return 1

This is my match function using too many cursors:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Match]
(
    @Subj1      varchar(8000),
    @Subj2      varchar(8000)
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    Set @Subj1 = IsNull(@Subj1,'')
    Set @Subj2 = IsNull(@Subj2,'')

    If @Subj1 = '' Or @Subj2 = ''
    Begin
        Return 0
    End

    If Lower(@Subj1) = Lower(@Subj2)
    Begin
        Return 1
    End

    Declare Subj1NamesCurr Cursor For --all separate names
        Select * From dbo.Split(@Subj1,',')

    Declare Subj2NamesCurr Cursor SCROLL For --all separate names
        Select * From dbo.Split(@Subj2,',')

    Open Subj1NamesCurr
    Open Subj2NamesCurr

    Declare @Sub1Names  varchar(8000)
    Declare @Sub2Names  varchar(8000)
    Declare @Sub1NamePart   varchar(8000)
    Declare @Sub2NamePart   varchar(8000)
    Declare @Sub1PartCount  tinyint = 0
    Declare @Sub2PartCount  tinyint = 0
    Declare @Sub1NamesPart  TABLE(Data varchar(8000))
    Declare @Sub2NamesPart  TABLE(Data varchar(8000))
    Declare @MatchCount int = 0
    Declare @TempCount int = 0

    Fetch From Subj1NamesCurr INTO @Sub1Names --fetch 1st name from 1st subject

    Insert into @Sub1NamesPart
            Select * From dbo.Split(@Sub1Names,';') --get names part from 1st subject's row

    Select @Sub1PartCount = Count(*) From @Sub1NamesPart


    While @@Fetch_Status = 0 --each names of 1st subject
    Begin

        Fetch First From Subj2NamesCurr into @Sub2Names

        While @@Fetch_Status = 0 --each names of 1st subject
        Begin
            Declare Sub1NameCurr Cursor For
                Select * From @Sub1NamesPart --name parts of 1st subject

            OPEN Sub1NameCurr

            Fetch From Sub1NameCurr into @Sub1NamePart

            Insert into @Sub2NamesPart
                Select * From dbo.Split(@Sub2Names,';') 

            Select @Sub2PartCount = Count(*) From @Sub2NamesPart
            Set @MatchCount = 0

            While @@Fetch_Status = 0 --splitted name of 1st subject
            Begin

                Declare Sub2NameCurr Cursor For
                    Select * From @Sub2NamesPart  --name parts of 2nd subject

                OPEN Sub2NameCurr

                Fetch From Sub2NameCurr into @Sub2NamePart

                Set @TempCount = 0

                While @@Fetch_Status = 0 --splitted name of 2nd subject
                Begin
                    Set @TempCount = @TempCount + 1
                    If dbo.Trim(Lower(@Sub1NamePart)) = dbo.Trim(Lower(@Sub2NamePart))
                    Begin

                        Set @MatchCount = @MatchCount + 1

                        If @Sub2PartCount = 1
                        Begin
                            Return 1
                        End
                    End
                    Else If Lower(Left(dbo.Trim(@Sub1NamePart),1)) = Lower(dbo.Trim(@Sub2NamePart)) Or 
                        Lower(Left(dbo.Trim(@Sub2NamePart),1)) = Lower(dbo.Trim(@Sub1NamePart))
                    Begin

                        Set @MatchCount = @MatchCount + 1
                    End

                    Fetch Next From Sub2NameCurr into @Sub2NamePart

                    Delete from @Sub2NamesPart
                    Insert into @Sub2NamesPart
                        Select * From dbo.Split(@Sub2Names,';') 
                End

                If @MatchCount = @Sub2PartCount
                Begin
                    Return 1
                End

                CLOSE Sub2NameCurr
                DEALLOCATE Sub2NameCurr

                Fetch Next From Sub1NameCurr into @Sub1NamePart

                Delete from @Sub1NamesPart
                Insert into @Sub1NamesPart
                    Select * From dbo.Split(@Sub1Names,';') --get names part from 1st subject's row

                Select @Sub1PartCount = Count(*) From @Sub1NamesPart                
            End

            CLOSE Sub1NameCurr
            DEALLOCATE Sub1NameCurr

        End
    End

    Close Subj1NamesCurr
    Deallocate Subj1NamesCurr

    Close Subj2NamesCurr
    Deallocate Subj2NamesCurr   
    Return 0

END
```

**Edit:** To create no confusions, Trim is just a function that does a LTrim and RTrim over your string. That's about it.

Comment: what should be your output from function? can you provide input and output sample?

Comment: What are the rules for matching? Perhaps there is a better way altogether.

Comment: @Nikola: I already gave the same data.

Comment: Data is fine, but rules are not clear. Why wouldn't `Patel; Ra, Patel, Raj` be acceptable but `Patel; R, Patel, Raj` would?

Comment: @Nikola: because Ra would mean different peron's name. People tend to write short form.

Comment: @Anand: I have written sample execution above. Can you please check now?

Comment: @Jack: would Select dbo.Match('P; R','Patel; Raj') return 1?

Comment: Joao: No, only for the cases I have written it should return 1.

Comment: And is the input only `Last Name; First Name` or can you have something like `Patel;Gupta;Raj;M` in your input?

Comment: Are you sure that `'R Patel', 'Raj Patel'` should **not** be a match?

Comment: @Nikola: Well ok, you are correct. If you want you can solve for that but that is not the requirement since in my real data I don't see that anywhere. I repeat, my primary requirement is only the cases that I have written. The only problem is it is way tooooo inefficient. If I run it over 500 records it takes about 3 seconds. Not at all acceptable!

Comment: @Joao: No, names are separated by , and first name and last and name are separated by ;.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for your examples, just don't know if it's faster than your solution.

The code should be pretty self explanatory and easy to change

```
DECLARE @str1 VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @str2 VARCHAR(max)
SELECT @str1 = 'Patel; Raj'
SELECT @str2 = 'Patel'

DECLARE @x1 XML
DECLARE @x2 XML
SELECT @x1 = CAST('<i>' + REPLACE(@str1, ',', '</i><i>') + '</i>' AS XML)
SELECT @x2 = CAST('<i>' + REPLACE(@str2, ',', '</i><i>') + '</i>' AS XML)


SELECT 
COUNT(*)
FROM
(
SELECT
p.number as Position,
LTRIM(RTRIM(x.value('.','VARCHAR(50)'))) AS Name
FROM
master..spt_values p
cross APPLY @x1.nodes('/i[position()=sql:column("number")]') n(x) 
where p.type = 'p'
) Names1
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT
p.number as Position,
LTRIM(RTRIM(x.value('.','VARCHAR(50)'))) AS Name
FROM
master..spt_values p
cross APPLY @x2.nodes('/i[position()=sql:column("number")]') n(x) 
where p.type = 'p'
) Names2
ON
Names1.Name = Names2.Name OR
(LTRIM(RTRIM(PARSENAME(Replace(Names1.Name,';','.'),1))) = LTRIM(RTRIM(PARSENAME(Replace(Names2.Name,';','.'),1))) 
AND
  LTRIM(RTRIM(PARSENAME(Replace(Names1.Name,';','.'),2))) = LTRIM(RTRIM(PARSENAME(Replace(Names2.Name,';','.'),2))) 
) OR
(LTRIM(RTRIM(PARSENAME(Replace(Names1.Name,';','.'),2))) = LTRIM(RTRIM(PARSENAME(Replace(Names2.Name,';','.'),2))) 
AND
  LEFT(LTRIM(RTRIM(PARSENAME(Replace(Names1.Name,';','.'),1))),1) = LTRIM(RTRIM(PARSENAME(Replace(Names2.Name,';','.'),1))) 
) OR
(LTRIM(RTRIM(PARSENAME(Replace(Names1.Name,';','.'),2))) = LTRIM(RTRIM(PARSENAME(Replace(Names2.Name,';','.'),2))) 
AND
  LTRIM(RTRIM(PARSENAME(Replace(Names1.Name,';','.'),1))) = LEFT(LTRIM(RTRIM(PARSENAME(Replace(Names2.Name,';','.'),1))),1) 
) OR
Names1.Name = LTRIM(RTRIM(PARSENAME(Replace(Names2.Name,';','.'),2)))
OR
Names2.Name = LTRIM(RTRIM(PARSENAME(Replace(Names1.Name,';','.'),2)))
```

Comment: This looks good but why doesn't it work on a table? I created a SQL function out of this logic and when I run over my table I get "Msg 9421, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
XML parsing: line 1, character 48, illegal name character". Any idea why?

Comment: It should work on a table, but it's probably receiving unexpected data. If you can identify what are the parameters that are causing that let me know.

Comment: I found when it throws error. Your function doesn't work when I pass in data as Select dbo.MatchSO('Freye; Allen E.','Christensen, O''Connor, Johnson & Kindness'). I get error XML parsing: line 1, character 48, illegal name character. Can you please tell why this is happening?

Comment: Sure: since we're converting to XML we need to be careful with special characters like the &. Three options: 1) remove all the special characters, 2) convert them to XML codes, before trying to parse the parameters list (in that example `&` should be replaced by `&amp;`), 3) convert them to something that is accepted by XML (just as a hack): in this case you could change `&` to `0` (assuming there aren't any 0s on people's names)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer that avoid cursors.  I think this might be best broken up into several functions, but tell me what you think and if it is faster for you.

For me, here are the performance comparison as a percentage of your original (FWIW): 
CPU: 47% 
Reads: 28%

So it does appear to be faster and with fewer reads, plus it works with all your test cases provided.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Match] 
(
@Subj1      varchar(8000), 
@Subj2      varchar(8000) 
) 
RETURNS bit AS 
BEGIN    

Set @Subj1 = IsNull(@Subj1,'')  
Set @Subj2 = IsNull(@Subj2,'')    

If @Subj1 = '' Or @Subj2 = ''    
Begin       
    Return 0  
End     

If Lower(@Subj1) = Lower(@Subj2) 
Begin    
    Return 1  
End   

 DECLARE @FullNames1 TABLE(Name varchar(200), SemiColon int, [Space] int)     
 DECLARE @FullNames2 TABLE(Name varchar(200), SemiColon int, [Space] int) 

 INSERT INTO @FullNames1
 SELECT 
    item, 
    CHARINDEX(';', item,0) as SemiColon,
    CHARINDEX(' ', item,0) as [Space]
 FROM
    dbo.Split(@Subj1, ',')


 INSERT INTO @FullNames2
 SELECT 
    item, 
    CHARINDEX(';', item,0) as SemiColon,
    CHARINDEX(' ', item,0) as [Space]
 FROM
    dbo.Split(@Subj2, ',')

 DECLARE @Names1 TABLE(FirstName varchar(100), LastName varchar(100))
 DECLARE @Names2 TABLE(FirstName varchar(100), LastName varchar(100))

 INSERT INTO @Names1
 SELECT 
    CASE WHEN SemiColon <> 0 THEN
        SUBSTRING(FullNames.Name,SemiColon+1, LEN(FullNames.Name))
    ELSE
        CASE WHEN FullNames.Space <> 0 THEN
            SUBSTRING(FullNames.Name, 1, FullNames.Space-1)     
        ELSE
            ''      
        END
    END AS FirstName,
    CASE WHEN SemiColon <> 0 THEN
        SUBSTRING(FullNames.Name, 1, SemiColon-1)       
    ELSE
        CASE WHEN FullNames.Space <> 0 THEN
            SUBSTRING(FullNames.Name,FullNames.Space+1, LEN(FullNames.Name))
        ELSE
            FullNames.Name  
        END
    END AS LastName
 FROM @FullNames1 FullNames

 INSERT INTO @Names2
 SELECT 
    CASE WHEN SemiColon <> 0 THEN
        SUBSTRING(FullNames.Name, SemiColon+1, LEN(FullNames.Name))
    ELSE
        CASE WHEN FullNames.Space <> 0 THEN
            SUBSTRING(FullNames.Name, 1, FullNames.Space-1)     
        ELSE
            ''      
        END
    END AS FirstName,
    CASE WHEN SemiColon <> 0 THEN
        SUBSTRING(FullNames.Name, 1, SemiColon-1)       
    ELSE
        CASE WHEN FullNames.Space <> 0 THEN
            SUBSTRING(FullNames.Name,FullNames.Space + 1, LEN(FullNames.Name))
        ELSE
            FullNames.Name  
        END
    END AS LastName
 FROM @FullNames2 FullNames


 UPDATE @Names1
 SET FirstName = Lower(LTrim(RTrim(FirstName))),
     LastName = Lower(LTrim(RTrim(LastName)))

 UPDATE @Names2
 SET FirstName = Lower(LTrim(RTrim(FirstName))),
     LastName = Lower(LTrim(RTrim(LastName)))


 IF EXISTS(
     SELECT *
     FROM @Names1 A
     INNER JOIN @Names2 B ON
     A.LastName = B.LastName AND
     (
        (A.FirstName = B.FirstName) OR
        (LEN(A.FirstName) = 1 AND A.FirstName = LEFT(B.FirstName, 1)) OR
        (LEN(B.FirstName) = 1 AND B.FirstName = LEFT(A.FirstName, 1)) OR
        (LEN(A.FirstName) = 0) OR
        (LEN(B.FirstName) = 0)
     ))
BEGIN
    RETURN 1
END

RETURN 0   
END
```